# Pyinstaller TypeError: attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eq'

Tags: python, pytest, pyinstaller

I am attempting to use pyinstaller to build an executable file for a python project.

My .spec file for the project is the following:

```
    # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['project.py', 'foo.py', 'bar.py'],
    pathex=['./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=['template.html'],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='project',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

My package has some dependencies, so I included the path to my venv in pathex and I am running `pyinstaller project.spec` with my venv activated.

When I do so, I get the following traceback and am unable to complete the build:

```
...
File "/Users/jesse/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 963, in <module>
    @attr.s(eq=False, auto_attribs=True)
TypeError: attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eq'
```

Finally, the relevant lines of code from the site package are as follows:

```
963.  @attr.s(eq=False, auto_attribs=True)
964.  class TerminalRepr:
965.      def __str__(self) -> str:
966.          # FYI this is called from pytest-xdist's serialization of exception
967.          # information.
968.          io = StringIO()
969.          tw = TerminalWriter(file=io)
970.          self.toterminal(tw)
971.          return io.getvalue().strip()
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it? I have read everything I can find and nothing seems to fix it. Perhaps it's a big in the underlying packages. I read that installing `attrs==19.2.0` could possibly fix it, but I have done so and am still getting this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update - I never resolved getting this to build with pyinstaller. Alternatively, I was able to successfully use the cx_Freeze package to build the project.